# get indexes of elements from a zigzag configuration

Tags: python

"How could I get the indexes of elements in an n-row array configuration?
The length of a row should be given by a string of length l.

For example:

For a 2-row array configuration with l=7, the elements (X) will have indexes:

```
elements = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (0, 6), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 7)]

[[X - X - X - X],
 [- X - X - X -]]
```

For a 3-rows array with l=8, the elements (X) will have indexes:

```
elements = [(0, 0), (0, 4), (0, 8), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 7), (2, 2), (2, 6)]

[[X - - - X - - - X],
 [- X - X - X - X -],
 [- - X - - - X - -]]
```

The idea is to extended to higher row numbers. Is there an "analytical" way of getting those indexes?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: By "analytical" I mean an equation or something that I could code

Comment: So `n` is the number of rows, but how do you know the number of columns?

Comment: the number of columns will be given by a string. I´ll edit my question to address it. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by "an analytical way". There's an obvious pattern, and it's trivial to write efficient code to generate those coordinates. What would an "analytical" solution look like?

Comment: What I mean is how to get code which can generate that pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my first shot at your problem:

```
def grid(width, depth):

    assert depth % 2 == 0
    height = depth//2 + 1

    lines = []
    for y in range(height):
        line = ''.join('X' if ((i+y) % depth == 0 or (i-y) % depth == 0) 
                           else '-' for i in range(width))
        lines.append(line)

    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

the `depth` is the parameter that defines how far the `X`s are spaces on fhe first line (the name is poorly chosen); the `width` is how many characters should be displayed per line.

this will only work for even `depth`s.

with outputs

```
-> print(grid(width=10, depth=2))
X-X-X-X-X-
-X-X-X-X-X

-> print(grid(width=10, depth=4))
X---X---X-
-X-X-X-X-X
--X---X---

-> print(grid(width=15, depth=6))
X-----X-----X--
-X---X-X---X-X-
--X-X---X-X---X
---X-----X-----
```

this was mostly trial & error so there is not much to explain...

---

if you prefer your `elements` representation - here is what you can do:

```
def grid_elements(width, depth):

    assert depth % 2 == 0
    height = depth//2 + 1

    elements = []
    for y in range(height):
        elements.extend((y, i) for i in range(width) 
                        if ((i+y) % depth == 0 or (i-y) % depth == 0))

    return elements
```

this creates the results:

```
-> print(grid_elements(width=10, depth=2))
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (0, 6), (0, 8), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 9)]

-> print(grid_elements(width=10, depth=4))
[(0, 0), (0, 4), (0, 8), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 9), (2, 2), (2, 6)]

-> print(grid_elements(width=15, depth=6))
[(0, 0), (0, 6), (0, 12), (1, 1), (1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 11), (1, 13), (2, 2), 
 (2, 4), (2, 8), (2, 10), (2, 14), (3, 3), (3, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a example of code that can do this.

```
import numpy as np

nb_row = 3; nb_column = 10;

separator_element = '-'; element = 'X';

#Initialise the size of the table
table = np.chararray((nb_row, nb_column), itemsize=1);
table[:] = separator_element; #By default, all have the separator element.

#Loop over each column: First column have element at first row. The element
#will after decrease and wrap around the nb of row.
#When at the bottom, switch to go up. At top, switch to go down.
position_element = 0; go_down = 1;
for no_column in xrange(0,nb_column):
    table[position_element,no_column] = element;

    #Case when go down.
    if go_down == 1:
        position_element = (position_element+1) % (nb_row);

        go_down = (position_element != (nb_row-1)); #Go up after go down.

    #Case when go up;
    else:
        position_element = (position_element-1) % (nb_row);

        go_down = (position_element == 0); #Go up after go down.
    #end

#end
print(table)
#[['X' '-' '-' '-' 'X' '-' '-' '-' 'X' '-']
#['-' 'X' '-' 'X' '-' 'X' '-' 'X' '-' 'X']
#['-' '-' 'X' '-' '-' '-' 'X' '-' '-' '-']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `itertools.groupby` here to create a dictionary that has the 
sublist indexes of interest as values and index of sublists as keys `{0: [0, 2, 4, 6], 1: [1, 3, 5, 7]}`, We can then use this on list that is generated using `n = 7`. From there we can modify the sublist using the indexes that are values for the corresponding sublist index in our keys.

```
from itertools import groupby
elements = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (0, 6), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 7)]


n = 7
d = {}

for k, g in groupby(elements, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    d[k] = [i[1] for i in g]

lst = [['-']*n for i in d]

for k in d:
    for i, v in enumerate(lst[k]):
        if i in d[k]:
            lst[k][i] = 'X'
    lst[k] = ' '.join(lst[k])

for i in lst:
    print(i)
#  X - X - X - X
#  - X - X - X -
```

Comment: "elements" should not be defined before?

Comment: I will put it in, just didnt include it since it was given @Maxwell'sDaemon